# Remainder when the polynomial $1+x^2+x^4+\cdots +x^{22}$ is divided by $1+x+x^2\cdots+ x^{11}$

Tags: polynomials

> **Question :** Find the remainder when the polynomial $1+x^2+x^4+\ldots +x^{22}$ is divided by $1+x+x^2+\cdots+ x^{11}$.

I tried using Euclid's division lemma, I.e.

$$P_1(x)=1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{22}$$

$$P_2(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{11}$$

Then for some polynomial $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$; we have

$$P_1(x)=Q(x)\cdot P_2(x)+R(x)$$

Now, we put the values of $x$ such that $R(x)=0$ and form equations, but this method is way too long and solving the 11 set of equations for 11 variable (Since $R(x)$ a polynomial of *at most* 10 degree) is impossible to do for a competitive exam where the average time for solving a question is 3 minutes.

Another method is using the original long division method, and following the pattern, we can predict $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$, but it's also very hard and time taking.

I am searching for a simple solution to this problem since last a week and now I doubt even we have a simple solution to this question.

Can you please give me a hint/solution on how to proceed to solve this problem in time?

Thanks!

Comment: When divided $P_1(x)$ by $P_2(x)$, you can simply replace $x^{12+k}$ by $x^k$ for each $k=0,2,4,6,8,10$ to get the remainder.

Comment: As a quick algebraic trick, I believe the quotient is the same polynomial with alternating signs.  That is $\sum_{i=0}^{11} (-1)^{i+1}x^i$.

Comment: @lulu How you got that?

Comment: @JaideepKhare  Direct calculation.  Well, a few examples with smaller powers than $11$ to conjecture the pattern, but then it's fairly easy to read off the coefficient of the product.  There should be a good cyclotomic argument for it, but I haven't got one yet.

Comment: @lulu I don't know that a cyclotomic argument is necessary. FWIW what matters here is that $11$ is odd, not that it's a prime.

Comment: @Batominovski's comment, posted before every answer below except one, provides a full and completely elementary solution to the problem, probably about two lines long. Until I upvoted it some minutes ago, this comment was not even upvoted, even less discussed, neither by the answerers nor by the OP.

Comment: @Did I couldn't understand it that time when the comment was posted, but I agree that it's my fault that had to ask Batominovski for further explanation then. BTW, did you just downvote the answer given by Bill Dubuque because it's copy of the comment?

Comment: Jaideep: Let me suggest that you concentrate on the comments (and answers) you receive rather than on the votes of other users, which, **by design**, are none of your business. (Which "further explanations" would you need to understand Batominovski's comment? It seems concise and quite clear to me...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$P_1(x)=\frac{x^{24}-1}{x^2-1}$$
$$P_2(x)=\frac{x^{12}-1}{x-1}$$
$$\frac{P_1(x)}{P_2(x)}=\frac{x^{24}-1}{x^{12}-1}\cdot\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}=\frac{x^{12}+1}{x+1}$$
Then Ruffini's rule tells us that the remainder of this *reduced* division is the polynomial $x^{12}+1$ evaluated at $-1$, i.e. 2. When the top and bottom of $\frac2{x+1}$ are multiplied by $\frac{x^{12}-1}{x^2-1}$, the denominator becomes $P_2(x)$ and the numerator gives the final answer of $\frac{2(x^{12}-1)}{x^2-1}=2+2x^2+2x^4+2x^6+2x^8+2x^{10}$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I should have addressed your questions, does this look OK?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\,P_n(x)=1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}=(x^n-1)/(x-1)\,$, then the problem is equivalent to finding the remainder of the division $\,P_{12}(x^2) / P_{12}(x)\,$.

The remainder is $\,2 \,P_6(x^2)\,$, which follows for $\,n=6\,$ from the general identity:

$$
\begin{align}
P_{2n}(x^2) = \frac{x^{4n}-1}{x^2-1} &= \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x-1} \, \frac{x^{2n}+1}{x+1} \\[5px]
 &= \, \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x-1} \, \frac{x^{2n}-1+2}{x+1} \\[5px]
 &= - \, \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x-1} \, \frac{(-x)^{2n}-1}{(-x)-1} + 2 \, \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^2-1} \\[5px]
 &= - \, P_{2n}(x) P_{2n}(-x) + 2 P_n(x^2)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The divisor $f = (\color{#c00}{x^{\large 12}\!-1})/(x-1)$ and $\,g = (1+\color{#c00}{x^{\large 12}})(1+x^{\large 2}+\cdots+x^{\large 10})\,$ is the dividend

hence $ \bmod\, f\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{x^{\large 12}\equiv 1}\ $ implies that $\,\  g\equiv\, (1\:+\ \color{#c00}1\,)\:(1+x^{\large 2}+\cdots+x^{\large 10})$

---

**Remark** $ $ Generally we can write $\ g = f_{\large 0} + f_{1} x^{\large 12}\! + \cdots + f_{\large k\,} x^{\large 12k}\! = h(\color{#c00}{x^{\large 12}}),\, $ $\,\deg f_{\large i} < 12$

hence as above $\ \color{#c00}{x^{\large  12}\equiv 1}\, \Rightarrow\, g\bmod f\,=\, f_{\large 0}+f_1+\cdots+ f_{\large k}\, =\ h(\color{#c00}1)$

---

Generally, $ $ if $\ f\mid \color{#c00}{x^{\large n}\!-1}\ $ then $\ g\bmod f\, =\, (g\bmod \color{#c00}{x^{\large n}\!\equiv 1})\bmod f$

Comment: I don't clearly understand why $x^{12}=1 \pmod{f}$ Can you please explain?

Comment: @Jaideep $\ \bmod f\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{f\equiv 0}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{x^{\large 12}\!-1} = (x\!-\!1)\color{#0a0}f\equiv 0,\,$ i.e. because $\,f\,$ divides $\,x^{\large 12}\!-\!1\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
p_2(x) &=& (x^6+1)(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)\\
       &=& (x^6+1)(x^3+1)(x^2+x+1)\\
       &=& (x^6+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)\\
       &=& (x+1)(x^6+1)(x^4+x^2+1)
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
p_1(x) &=& (x^{12}+1)(x^{10}+x^8+x^6+x^4+x^2+1)\\
       &=& (x^{12}+1)(x^6+1)(x^4+x^2+1)
\end{eqnarray*}

Write $$p_1(x) = k(x)p_2(x) +r(x)$$ then $(x^6+1)(x^4+x^2+1)$ divides $r(x)$.

So $r(x) = (x^6+1)(x^4+x^2+1)s(x)$ where $s(x)$ is constant. So $$x^{12}+1 = k(x)(x+1)+ s(x)$$ Put $x=-1$ and we get: $s(-1)= 2$.